# How can I get the ID of my Window popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the ID of my Window ?

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    if (alterado == 1) {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
});
```

How can I get the ID of my `window.opener.location` ?

I need to put a block in this window like `$("#window").block(message:"loading");`, or a div that exists in the parent window.

Comment: Could you explain your question more? Where/when do you need this id, and why from the `location` you already have your `window`reference??

Comment: When I close some popup, the caller has to reload. So, I just want a blockUI while the page isn't ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.opener.$("#window").block(message:"loading");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `window.opener.document` to get access to the opener document.
like

```
var doc = window.opener.document;
doc.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = "Loading"
```